# Change the language in the <input type = "date" /> instruction

Tags: date, input, types

I am developing an app that use two languages (english and spanish), so I need to change the language in the frontend. My question is related with the instruction:

```
<input type = "date" name = "date" />
```

How can you specify to type date the language? If I use this simple code:
    
        
        
            from: 
            to: 
        
    
It always show me the calendar with the months and days in spanish, so I need to know how can I change it to english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Safari and Google Chrome don't respect lang attribute, and they always apply browser's locale.  AFAIK, page authors have no ways to specify language.